# Replace (Change) the icons -issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I changed the icon to the registered API using the image. However, it is applied well in the publisher, but the icon image is not reflected in the devportal. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Publisher Icon Images

[image: publisher images i changed]

Devportal icon images

[image: devportal images]

Comment: Can you share the version of the API Manager? Also, can you share whether you are using a single all-in-one API Manager node or you are having a distributed API Manager deployment in your environment?

Comment: Hi @Athiththan,   API Manager version 4.0.0... Currently, the program is installed on a single CentOS server for testing.

Comment: Have you applied any custom themes to the API Manager? Or are you observing the behaviour without any Theme changes in your environment? Furthermore, can you also try invoking the following [API](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v2/devportal-v2/#tag/APIs/paths/~1apis~1{apiId}~1thumbnail/get) and verify whether the thumbnail image is returned as response?

Comment: @Athiththan, We are using custom themes. I will have to check with other developer, but we're customizing the Devportal UI and using it.

Comment: Since you are using custom themes for the Devportal, it is good to check the customizations made to the API Listing and API Thumbnail components to verify whether any necessary code block is missed or not. It might help if you do a side by side verification with the default source of the Devportal react components with the customizations made.

Comment: Appreiciate @Athiththan, let me check~